# AngularJS child route always redirect to otherwise using $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I have this routing config and the problem is that whenever I access a child route, it always redirects to `otherwise`. Which in this case is `/login`

```
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController as loginCtrl',
    })
    .state('reports', {
        abstract: true,
        url: "/reports",
        templateUrl: 'views/container.html',
    })
    .state('reports.create', {
        url: '/reports-create',
        templateUrl: 'views/reports.html',
        controller: 'ReportsController as reportsCtrl',
    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

I have set the `/reports` to `abstract:true`. This is because I do not want the users to access the `/reports` so they should be redirected to `/reports-create` instead.

Now whenever user access either `/reports` or `/reports-create`, they're always redirected to `/login`.

But if I make `reports.create` to `create`, I am able to access `/reports-create` but I am able to access `/reports` as well in which should not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

> Now whenever user access either /reports or /reports-create, they're always redirected to /login

You won't be able to access `/reports`, because it's abstract. Also, you have to access the reports-create on the url: `/reports/reports-create`, because the abstract parent state "prepends" it's url to the child urls.
See the documentation here: [Abstract states](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-&-nested-views#abstract-states)

Also make sure, that the parent state has a `ui-view` somewhere in it's template, it is required, it is where the child state templates will be rendered to (check the documentation I linked above).

One more thing: I would rename my child url from `/reports-create` to simply `/create`, this way the final URL will be much better: `/reports/create`.

Comment: Yes, I have the `<div ui-view></div>` on the html. Accessing the `/reports` is expected to redirect on the `/login` page but the `/create` should not in which is happening. Any more that should be considered?

Comment: Are you trying `/reports/create`, right? :) (cause you wrote simply `/create` again).
If yes, then I don't have any other idea, create an example which shows the problem, e.g. in JSFiddle or something similar. Your config looks ok to me, maybe the problem is somewhere else in the code